# Entering random number sequence seed under surveillance

Tags: password-protection, password-encryption, random-seed

I'm trying to transmit a continuous sequence of random numbers from my computer over to another country (for validation purpose). This is a sequence of pseudo random numbers recursively generated from a seed. Now imagine the local government agency is trying to hack my computer to decipher my sequence so they can replicate and transmit their own version while cutting off my stream. To prevent this I need to make sure the seed is not known to them. This is difficult because assume my computer is being totally bugged and monitored. How to enter the seed into the computer without them finding out?

Comment: Maybe you are going in wrong direction? What is your usecase? Do you use any type of authentication or authorization on your data? Any consistency check with crc, tokens, etc?

Comment: There is no data. I'm just transmitting a sequence to a different country where someone else will verify if they have the same sequence (this person in the other country knows the seed). I have to make sure the local government agency does not find the seed. Is it clear now?